# jQuery find current tr cells

Tags: jquery

I have datatable like below `HTML` code, after `doubleClick` on each row automaticaly insert `SAVE` and `EDIT` buttons to end of current `tr`, I'm using datatables class for create data in table and I can't find current `tr` cells such as `eq(0 ~ 3)` with `jQuery`.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input value="admin">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input value="pishguy@gmail.com">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input value=" A">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input value=" B">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input value="C">
            </td>
            <td>
                <ul class="styledlist" style="width: 50px;">
                    <li style="line-height: 13px; width: 30px; float: right;" class="save_category">SAVE</li>
                    <li style="margin-right: 6px; line-height: 13px; width: 30px; float: right;" class="cancel_save_category">CANCEL</li>
                </ul>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**jQuery:**
this below codes dont work currectly

```
alert( $(this).parent().siblings('td:first').text() ); 
alert( $(this).closest('tr').children('td:eq(0)').text())  ;
```

I have any row in table and I want to find currect `tr` cells with `save` and `cancel` buttons.

Comment: _"after doubleClick"_ - Please show your entire double-click handler. The two lines you show don't make sense to us if we don't know what `this` is - you say they aren't working correctly, but what do they actually do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0) input').val());   // admin
alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1) input').val());   // pishguy@gmail.com
```

In your code:

```
$(this).closest('tr').children('td:eq(0)').text();
```

You are looking for the text inside the first `td` but there's no text there, you have a input there with some value. So, you need to find the input inside the closest `tr` and then get its value using `val()`.

**Assumption**: That `this` here represents either the *SAVE/CANCEL* here

Comment: thank you very much. i want to replace any text into cells with this code`alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').html('ddd'));` i need to hide input elements and putting text with that, can you help me?

Comment: Here's the code to hide the input and set a new text inside the td: `var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        $tr.find('td:eq(0) input').hide();
        $tr.find('td:eq(0)').append('<span>New Text</span>');`

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you click on SAVE button in particular row,

then your click handler as follow,

```
function clickHandler() {
                    var $this = $(this), //this will represent the button
                        currentRow = $this.closest('tr'),
                        currentRowCells = currentRow.children();

                    //Now can access any cell within current row using currentRowCells Object, as follow
                    var firstCell = currentRowCells.eq(0),
                        secondCell = currentRowCells.eq(1);
                }
```